# How to create a repository with ssh:// access on a server

Tags: linux, git, version-control, ssh, repository

I have a small machine running Debian and can access it via `ssh -l user host`. Now I created a git repository in a folder on that machine.

The thing that I can not figure out is: What do I have to do, that git would let me access that repository in the way `git push ssh://yourserver.com/~you/proj.git +master`

Or in other words: what means `ssh://`, and how do I set up access to a repository using that protocol?

Thank you for your help/hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been through this whole problem before. I ended up settling on [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/1-INSTALL.mkd#_package_method_directly_on_the_server_using_RPM_DEB) to manage git & ssh. It's very easy to install (if you use the package method) and it makes maintaining repositories easy.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm after a whole morning of compiling all that stuff (git >1.6.2 + dependencies) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

See this [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/).
In particular, see Chapter 4, "Git on the server".

It's quite easy to setup =)

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of people use gitosis for this. But that does not support ~you.

Comment: Gitosis is also abandonware for over a year now. Gitolite is to be preferred.